# How to decrypt multiple files to stdout in gpg2?

Tags: gnupg

`gpg2 --decrypt-files *.gpg` - fail, to creates appropriate files without `.gpg` extension.

```
gpg2 --output - --decrypt-files *.gpg  
gpg: --output doesn't work for this command
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `gpg-agent` and re-execute `gpg2` for each file:

```
export GPG_AGENT_INFO=...
for i in *.gpg; do
    gpg2 --batch -qd < $i
done
```